# Cant render an array of object from context file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, render, array.prototype.map

for some reason i cant render my array of objects 'data'. I'm using react and context hook. I dont get any error in my browser.

Here is the repository of this problem

https://github.com/santanafx/teste-context

file index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { ContextProvider } from './context/globalContext';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ContextProvider>
      <App />
    </ContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

file App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import { Context } from './context/globalContext';

function App() {

  const { data } = React.useContext(Context);

  return (
    <div >
      {data.map((element) => {
        <div key={data.id}>
          <div>{element.id}</div>
          <div>{element.descricao}</div>
          <div>{element.edicao}</div>
        </div>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

export default App;```
file globalContext.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const Context = React.createContext();

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

    var data = [{
        id: 'teste1',
        edicao: '1',
        descricao: '2',
    },
    {
        id: 'teste2',
        edicao: '1',
        descricao: '2',
    },
    {
        id: 'teste3',
        edicao: '1',
        descricao: '2',
    }]

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{ data }}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}
```

I tried to use react hook of state at my context file but i didnt have success. For some reason it seems that i cant render an object from my context hook.

Comment: What renders instead? Have you tried adding some text so you can see if it renders?

Comment: Missing `return` in the `map` in App.js (or replace the inner curly braces with parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 typos in your `App` component:

```
return (
  <div>
    {data.map((element) => { <-- you're not returning anything from the map's callback
      <div key={data.id}> <-- use the element's id
        <div>{element.id}</div>
        <div>{element.descricao}</div>
        <div>{element.edicao}</div>
      </div>
    })}
  </div>
);
```

And this is how it should look after fixing the problems:

You have 2 typos in your `App` component ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-map-typos-q15jfh?file=/src/index.js)):

```
return (
  <div>
    {data.map((element) => (callback
      <div key={element.id}> <-- use the element's id
        <div>{element.id}</div>
        <div>{element.descricao}</div>
        <div>{element.edicao}</div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```js
  {data.map((element) => {
        <div key={data.id}>
          <div>{element.id}</div>
          <div>{element.descricao}</div>
          <div>{element.edicao}</div>
        </div>
      })}
```

To this

```js
  {data.map((element) => (
        <div key={data.id}>
          <div>{element.id}</div>
          <div>{element.descricao}</div>
          <div>{element.edicao}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
```